# Remove previously selected item from a list

Tags: c#, list, combobox

So I've got several comboBox's that add to a list, and I've been trying to store the previous selected item but it seems to only come back null. 
Here is my code

```
List<string> CE = new List<string>();
public string Prev1;
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventsArgs e) 
{
    if(Prev1 != null)
    {
        CE.Remove(Prev1);
    } 
    CE.Add(comboBox1.Text);
}
private void comboBox1_Enter(object sender, EventsArgs e) 
{
    Prev1 = comboBox1.SelectedText;
}
```

Any idea why Prev1 keeps returning null?

Comment: Prev1 is always null because you defined it as a null object. somewhere you should add a value to it

Comment: It should be getting a value from the selected comboBox

Comment: so you enter the combobox, that gets the currently displayed text. then you change the current item and add the text from before to your list. my question is: do you set the selected item in the combobox before giving it focus? by default there should no item be selected so you gotta do that first to prevent `SelectedText` to return nothing, am I wrong?

Comment: perhaps its null because you have set it to be only set on enter.. not changing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should look like to store the previous selected item:

```
    List<string> CE = new List<string>();
    public string Prev1;
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Prev1))
        {
            CE.Remove(Prev1);
        }

        CE.Add(comboBox1.Text);
        Prev1 = comboBox1.Text;
    }
```

in your code you didn't really stored the previous one except for the enter event (which is presume is not what you want)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Text` property instead of `SelectedText` in `comboBox1_Enter`.